# Defer block is not executed

Tags: swift, deferred

I have the following swift code executing in playground:

```
func A() {
    print ("Hello")
    guard 1 == 2 else {
        return
    }
    defer {
        print ("World")
    }
}
  
A()
```

I expected to see

```
Hello
World
```

Instead only the `Hello` is printed. Why is this? What am I missing?

Here is a better example:

```
enum MyError: ErrorType {
    case TriggerDefer
}

func throwsMyError() throws {
    let myzero = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))
    
    guard myzero > 1 else {
        throw MyError.TriggerDefer
    }
}

func A() throws {
    try throwsMyError()
    
    defer {
        print ("Hello World")
    }
}
```

---

### As per the answers and comments, the correct way to do this (with an example) is

```
enum MyError: ErrorType {
    case TriggerDefer
}

func throwsMyError() throws {
    let myzero = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))

    print("Hello")

    guard myzero > 1 else {
        throw MyError.TriggerDefer
    }
}

func A() throws {        
    defer {
        print ("World")
    }
     
    try throwsMyError()
}
```

The output will now be

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: What you're missing is that `defer` is not magic. It is executable code, just like any other code. If the path of execution never encounters it, there is nothing to be deferred. This is why it should always be _dead first_ in the block on whose exit it is to be executed.

Comment: @matt Thanks, this comment explains it better than the current answer

Comment: Well, then I'll give it as an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're missing is that `defer`is not magic. It is executable code, just like any other code. If the path of execution never encounters it, there is nothing to be deferred. This is why it should always be *dead first* in the block on whose exit it is to be executed — so that we *guarantee* that it *is* encountered.

Answer (score 6):

Put the `defer` block before the scope is exited:

```
func A() {
    print ("Hello")
    defer {
        print ("World")
    }
    guard 1 == 2 else {
        return
    }
}

A()
```

Comment: Actually, I would suggest you tell him to put it _dead first_, even before the `print` statement.