# Swift defer statement placement

Tags: swift

Does it matter where the `defer` statement is included within the context of a given scope?  Are all these the same?

```
//1
{
    openFile();

    guard let x=y else {
        return
    }

    defer {
        closeFile()
    }
}

//2
{
    openFile();

    defer {
        closeFile()
    }

    guard let x=y else {
        return
    }
}

//3
{
    defer {
        closeFile()
    }

    openFile();

    guard let x=y else {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Defer block is not executed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36169415/2976878)

Comment: @Hamish: I would consider it a duplicate. That Q&A contains all information to answer this question as well.

Comment: Thanks that answers it.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I agree. I was only hesitant because that question was about a specific problem, whereas this one was more abstract.

Comment: @Hamish: Yes, that is a valid point. On the other hand, an answer to this one would be mainly a repetition of the arguments in the other threads. Not sure how to handle this optimally.